# sharePoint 2010 User Profile Syncronization

Tags: user-profile-service

In this Blog, Where exactly in sharePoint 2010 the dialog box that says import vs export dropdown in the UPSS configuration?  Thanks.

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/05/31/does-sharepoint-2010-mess-with-my-active-directory/

Answer (score 3):

This is full 'road map'

- Central administration > Application Management > Service
  Applications > Manage service applications
- click User Profile service
- People > Manage User Properties
- select desired property > menu Edit
- scroll to bottom