# SharePoint 2010 User Profile two way Synchronization

Tags: user-profile-service

in this blog/guide.. where exactly is two way sycnchronization defined and managed? Not that we want to do this - but just want to know where that is defined?

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/05/31/does-sharepoint-2010-mess-with-my-active-directory/

1. “By default, no user profile property is set to Export. You must explicitly define the user profile properties that you want to export back to the directory service from the user profile store.” This is done by SharePoint administrator and is required only for the two-way synchronization

Comment: possible duplicate of [sharePoint 2010 User Profile Syncronization](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20429/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-syncronization)

Comment: Missed that. It sure does look like the same question.

Answer (score 2):

In Central Admin, Under the Manage Profile Service page, in the people section.

Technet has a detailed step by step:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx