# Two-Way User Profile Synchronization from / to AD

Tags: 2013, user-profile, my-site, active-directory, user-profile-service

I am wondering about the following problem - say I have MySites configured on my SharePoint Server 2013 environment and the users' profile properties like address, telephone number and so forth are mapped to be synced from AD.

Now some user changes his telephone number and updates the data in his profile in SharePoint - now I would like that change to be applied to AD automatically, sort of a two-way synchronization.

Is there a solution to the scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, UPS in SharePoint 2010 does not provide real synchronization, it's a designed limitation.
Mapping direction cannot be edited, first you need to remove the old mapping and then we have to recreate it with new mapping direction, directions (import and export) for same properties cannot exist at the same time.

For more information kindly go through the following URL's

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925.aspx#section6

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#Phase4

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2010/11/22/mapping-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2010-to-ldap-attributes.aspx

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

“By default, no user profile property is set to Export. You must explicitly define the user profile properties that you want to export back to the directory service from the user profile store.” This is done by SharePoint administrator and is required only for the two-way synchronization

[Please read this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20494/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-two-way-synchronization)

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate Forefront Identity Manager with the SharePoint Connector.  This will allow you to work with the properties within the FIM Metaverse for export/import decision making.